# Android RSS app that updates every 1-5 seconds?

Tags: android, rss

Could anyone advice me, how can I update the RSS feed every 1-5 seconds on my Android? I have tried many apps but the fastest one updates every 15 seconds.

Comment: Create a Thread which call the api every 5 seconds

Comment: honestly I don't understand what you say :)
is there any link with instruction?

Comment: I mean if you want to fetch RSS data every 5 seconds put the method in the thread which runs every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler handler; 

handler= new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                FetchRSSData(); // method called for fetching RSS data

                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }
        }, 5000); // thread for 5 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you! But I am not a programmer. Where can I past it so that it works?

Comment: Fllow this link for get RSS data to andorid [Link](https://www.journaldev.com/20126/android-rss-feed-app)

Comment: I downloaded that app, but there is no apk file